Correct permutation design for envfit (nested study design)?
I have the following study design: 8 locations, 5 forest types/"stands" (Plots) per location (D,DB,B,FB,F). In every plot I sampled spiders and identified them. I did an 3 dimensional NMDS with Morisita-Horn index.
Additionally, with the help of the function envfit() I want to check if certain environmental variables are correlated to changes in the community stucture.
nmds_raw <- metaMDS(matrix_env_plot[,2:49], k = 3, distance = "horn", autotransform = FALSE )

env = matrix_env_plot[,c( "litter_depth_avg","annual_air_temp_avg","altitude","annual_rain_tot","Be_APA","Do_APA","Sp_APA")] 

I think that I have to restrict the permutations because of the nested studydesign so that permutations occour only within locations:
CTRL.t <- how(within = Within(type = "free"),
              blocks = matrix_env_plot$location,
              nperm = 999,
              observed = TRUE)

en = envfit(nmds_raw, env, choices = c(1:3), permutations = CTRL.t, na.rm = TRUE)


The result is the following:
***VECTORS

                       NMDS1    NMDS2    NMDS3     r2 Pr(>r)    
litter_depth_avg    -0.41745  0.77921 -0.46751 0.2940  0.001 ***
annual_air_temp_avg  0.20193  0.07438  0.97657 0.1268  0.862    
altitude            -0.22305 -0.06187 -0.97284 0.2836  0.657    
annual_rain_tot     -0.07598 -0.11178 -0.99082 0.2343  0.835    
Be_APA              -0.41850  0.84927 -0.32185 0.4342  0.001 ***
Do_APA               0.67322 -0.73174  0.10647 0.1366  0.088 .  
Sp_APA               0.06577 -0.90513  0.42001 0.1592  0.059 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Blocks:  matrix_env_plot$location 
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

The climatic variables (temperature, annual rain sum and altitude) do not show a significant correlation. This is not surprising, because they vary little within one location.
But in my NMDS I see a clear seperation between 4 locations which are further in the north and 4 locations which are further in south and I think that the altitude, annual air temperature and the annual rain sum might be factors which are responsible for those differences.
With which permutation design can I check whether the different climatic conditions between (!) the locations are correlated to the change in the community composition?
Would this be a correct approach? :
CTRL.b <- how(within = Within(type = "none"),
              plots = Plots(strata = matrix_env_plot$location, type = "free")
              nperm = 999,
              observed = TRUE)


The permutation design
CTRL.b <- how(within = Within(type = "none"),
              plots = Plots(strata = matrix_env_plot$location, type = "free")
              nperm = 999,
              observed = TRUE)

will not include variation within locations in the null distribution of the test statistic.
Coupled with a model that estimates the magnitudes of the effects of the variables of interest, this design can be used to do what you want.

would it also be correct to not restrict the permutations for the climatic variables and altitude? could I just run unrestricted permuations ?

I doubt it; in what way are the climate variables and altitude different form the environmental variables you mention in your question. Altitude probably varies between not within locations, as I would presume climate. In which case you need to permute samples among locations while keeping the samples in the observed order within locations. This is exactly what I showed in my answer.

Yes, exactly. While environmental data like litter depth vary within locations due to different tree species that make up the forest stands, altitude and climate variables barely vary within locations but rather between locations. So the permuation design which you confirmed is correct but I don't know how to set up a model which estimates the magnitudes of the effects of the variables and what use I should make of it.
